# Override abstract type member in stackable trait pattern

Tags: scala, traits, abstract-type

Suppose we want to define ways how to accumulate results over some data:

```
case class Data(x: Int, y: Int)
```

We define a trait to do so:

```
trait Accumulator {
  type R   
  def add(acc: R, d: Data): R
  def zero: R
}
```

And a simple implementation:

```
trait XAccumulator extends Accumulator {
  type R = Int
  def add(acc: Int, d: Data) = acc + d.x
  def zero = 0
}
```

I would like to use the stackable-trait pattern to use multiple of these simple accumulators:

```
trait TraceYAccumulator extends Accumulator {
  abstract override type R = (Seq[Int], super.R)
  // fails:
  // `abstract override' modifier not allowed for type members

  def add(acc: R, d: Data) = {
    val r = super.add(acc._2, d)
    (acc._1 :+ d.y, r)
  }

  def zero = (Seq.empty[Int], super.zero)
}
```

Apparently I am not allowed to override an abstract type member. How can I alter the result type of the overridden methods using the stackable trait pattern?

My second approach was to use type parameters:

```
trait Accumulator[R] {
  def add(acc: R, d: Data): R
  def zero: R
}

trait XAccumulator extends Accumulator[Int] {
  def add(acc: Int, d: Data) = acc + d.x
  def zero = 0
}
```

But now it becomes really strange:

```
trait TraceYAccumulator[T] extends Accumulator[(Seq[Int], T)] {
  this: Accumulator[T] =>

  def add(acc: (Seq[Int], T), d: Data): (Seq[Int], T) = {
    val r = this.add(acc._2, d)
    // fails: overloaded method value add with alternatives:
    // (acc: (Seq[Int], T),d: Data)(Seq[Int], T) <and>
    // (acc: _14695,d: Data)_14695 cannot be applied to (T, Data)
    (acc._1 :+ d.y, r)
  }
  def zero: (Seq[Int], T) = (Seq.empty[Int], this.zero)
}
```

Since the super-class and the mixed-in class have the same method names (obviously), we cannot refer to the correct methods. Is my only option to use composition?

How can I stack such kind of operations?

Comment: Not sure if this is going to work as you desire it to. The stackable trait pattern involves the functions chaining to each other by calling super. If each trait in the chain could possible have a different generic type then I don't see how the calls can chain properly. It could work if they were all parameterized with the same type perhaps.

Comment: @cmbaxter The calls can chain properly because the stacking traits take the stacked-on trait's return type in account for their return type. Of course the final return type of the whole stack will depend on the order of the stacked traits. I cannot see where the theoretical problem with my approach is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach has a fundamental theoretical problem:

Suppose we are allowed to write these traits. Then consider the following:

```
val acc = new XAccumulator with TraceYAccumulator
val xacc = acc: XAccumulator
```

Since `xacc` is an `XAccumulator`, we know that `x.R =:= Int`. Ooops.

The second approach has an implementation problem: You cannot inherit from different instances of the same trait.

```
illegal inheritance; anonymous class $anon inherits different type instances of trait Accumulator: Accumulator[Int] and Accumulator[(Seq[Int], Int)]
```

Therefore, composition (or maybe some typeclass hackery) seems to be the only option.